# Disabling function inside textarea "onKeyUp"

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm trying to disable `test()` function inside a `textarea` tag.

```
onKeyUp="test()" // Not textarea
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="aaa" onKeyUp="test()"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" onclick="disable()" value="Disable" />
<input type="button" onclick="enable()" value="Enable" />


<script type="text/javascript">
function disable(){document.getElementById('aaa').disabled=true;}
function enable(){document.getElementById('aaa').disabled=false;}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I disable and enable this `test()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.setAttribute` to add and remove the value of any attribute of the selected element, including `onKeyUp`.

To disable:

```
// Instead of using:
document.getElementById('aaa').disabled=true;

// try:
document.getElementById('aaa').setAttribute("onKeyUp", "");
```

To enable:

```
// Instead of using:
document.getElementById('aaa').disabled=false;

// try:
document.getElementById('aaa').setAttribute("onKeyUp", "test()");
```

Check the snippet:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="aaa" onKeyUp="test()"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" onclick="disable()" value="Disable" />
<input type="button" onclick="enable()" value="Enable" />


<script type="text/javascript">
  function disable() {
    document.getElementById('aaa').setAttribute("onKeyUp", "");
  }

function enable() {
    document.getElementById('aaa').setAttribute("onKeyUp", "test()");
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function test() {
    alert("enabled");
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)